# keydown function assigned to two keys but is fired when any key is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, keydown

Q: I assigned keydown to ONLY 2 keys, however, if i press any keyboard key, the script is fired. Can someone tell me if this is a formatting issue, just by looking at the script?

This keydown jQuery works for me, when the right arrow is pressed a modal moves to the next, and when the left key is pressed it will trigger the previous modal.

```js
$("div[id^='myModal']").keydown(function(e){
    var currentModal = $(this);
    if (e.which == 39){
    }else{
  currentModal.modal('hide');
  currentModal.closest("div[id^='myModal']").prevAll("div[id^='myModal']").first().modal('show');  
    }
     var currentModal = $(this);
    if (e.which == 37){
    }else{
  currentModal.modal('hide');
  currentModal.closest("div[id^='myModal']").nextAll("div[id^='myModal']").first().modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of the one that you have tried and didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems arise from your use of the `if` statements. Looks to me as if you should change your code:

```js
$("div[id^='myModal']").keydown(function(e){
        var currentModal = $(this);
        if (e.which === 39) {
          currentModal.modal('hide');
          currentModal.closest("div[id^='myModal']").prevAll("div[id^='myModal']").first().modal('show');  
        } else if (e.which === 37) {
          currentModal.modal('hide');
          currentModal.closest("div[id^='myModal']").nextAll("div[id^='myModal']").first().modal('show');
        }
    });
```

Basically, what your code says is "If the left arrow key is pressed do nothing, otherwise do something with the previous modal" and then "If the right arrow key is pressed do nothing, otherwise do something with the next modal".

Comment: Brilliant! This worked for me. I am so grateful for the help and I'm so happy there is a community out there to help. Keep it up friend!